# SQL Server Report Builder SUM IF

Tags: sql-server-2012, reporting

I have a table which display various data and what I want is it to calculate a percentage in which the total has increased by, so for example: 
Total is £1000 
TotalAfterMarkup is £1500

```
=SUM(Fields!Total.Value -  
Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value) /       
(Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value)
```

the above code calculates the Percentage to -50% which is incorrect but ill be able to work that out. What i want is to now put this statement into an SUM IF statement. currently i get the #Error if the TotalAfterMarkup < 1  so i need something like

```
IF TotalAfterMarkup.Value >0 THEN

=SUM(Fields!Total.Value -  
Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value) /       
(Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value) 

ELSE 0.00%
```

is this possible, thanks for any help guys

Comment: NOTE: I dont need the SQL Server code, im using Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 and am trying to calculate the expression :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to comment, otherwise I wouldn't post this as an answer. Really, I need a little more information. Are you doing this as an expression within the report builder or as part of your dataset?

If its part of your dataset then I suggest using a `case` statement.

```
case
when TotalAfterMarkup.Value >0
then SUM(Fields!Total.Value -  
   Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value) /       
  (Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value) 
else '0.00%'
end [MyFieldName]
```

Using an IIF Statement: ("Dataset = Your Dataset Name")

```
=IIF(Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value, "CostTable") >0, SUM(Fields!TotalCost.Value,   "CostTable") - (Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value, "CostTable") / (Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value, "CostTable"), "0.00%")
```

Comment: I am doing this as an expression within a textbox, the fields (TotalAfterMarkup, Total) are contained within the dataset and the calculation is made based on there values

Comment: Needed to add the dataset Name to the expression. I've tested this and it works for me.

Comment: sorry, new to this, started using it a few hours ago, I did that however still no luck

    =IIF(Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value, "CostTable" >0,
    SUM(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "CostTable" -  
    Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value, "CostTable") /  
    (Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value, "CostTable"),
    "0.00%")

Comment: =IIF(Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value, "CostTable") >0, SUM(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "CostTable") - (Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value, "CostTable") / (Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value, "CostTable"), "0.00%")

Comment: i understand exactly what you code does but it wont work and its should :| 

This is the error code i get from the above statement:

The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox224.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.

Comment: does removing the quotation marks and the percentage sign fix it? ie) Change 0.00% to 0? Also, did the answer above work?

Comment: solved, I didnt need to include the dataset and the expression was working, I now have 1 random field which says error no matter what I put in the expression haha, so thats another issue, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
=IIF(TotalAfterMarkup.Value > 0,(SUM(Fields!Total.Value -  
Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value)/(Fields!TotalAfterMarkup.Value)),0)
```

The IIF function is the one you use for evaluating conditions in SSRS:

[Expression Examples (Report Builder and SSRS) - See decision function section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx)